# Web Page Script to Sort Order of Columns (not order of rows)

Tags: javascript, html

(Searched the web and here for a couple hours with no success...novice level programmer)

What I have: Table with single row, containing many short columns. The columns are entered chronologically in the HTML, adding new columns to the right. (This long row is in a short height, wide width page displayed in an iframe, and is manually scrolled left/right.)

What I want to do: Create a **toggle-link reverse column display order** so that the newest columns appear to the left and oldest to the right when desired.

Since my membership is new, I can't post a screenshot. So here's my best work-around attempt:

**The web page** this solution is to be applied to is found at:

thetransformer.us   (home page, in the upper area iframe file)

**A screenshot** of a text illustration of desired output of a solution is found at:

thetransformer.us/images/reverse-col-order-illustration.jpg

CODE_BELOW: (Main page:) & (iframe file code (not scrollable DIV as I indicated earlier)
Many lines of the same type of code blocks omitted.

```
<div>
<iframe src="gallery.html" scrolling="yes" width="645" height="300" class="rounded10"></iframe>
</div>


<body style="margin:15px; background-image:url(images/bgrepeat.png)">
<div id="pl_main">
<button onclick="reverseOrder()">Reverse</button> <span style="color:white;">The horizontal link list is currently unavailable. Use View <span style="color:#99ccff;">Table of Contents</span> below.</span>
<table class="gallery">
<tr id="tableRow">
<td valign="top" id="19851"><a href="85-3.pdf#zoom=100" target="_blank">
<span style="color:#99ccff;">1985</span> Jul<br /><img src="pl_thumbs/1985-07_thumb.jpg" />
</a></td>
<td valign="top" id="19861"><a href="86-0102.pdf#zoom=100" target="_blank">
<span style="color:#99ccff;">1986</span> Jan-Feb<br /><img src="pl_thumbs/1986-01-02_thumb.jpg" />
</a></td>
<td valign="top" id="19862"><a href="86-0304.pdf#zoom=100" target="_blank">
<span style="color:#99ccff;">1986</span> Mar-Apr<br /><img src="pl_thumbs/1986-03-04_thumb.jpg" />
</a></td>
<td valign="top" id="19863"><a href="86-0506.pdf#zoom=100" target="_blank">
<span style="color:#99ccff;">1986</span> May-Jun<br /><img src="pl_thumbs/1986-05-06_thumb.jpg" />
</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, Doug

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also would be helpful to give the actual html produced as an example.

Comment: To: @Mike Ante I am not a JavaScript programmer, but I have tried to adapt a script I'm using for sorting rows to sort columns. But not knowing what I'm doing prevented that from happening. The only thing I found on the web was a post about how to reverse column order using VBA in Excel. I may actually use that at some point...but it's a different project (working with Access and Excel VBA).

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]: Here is the solution of reversing the column in JQuery.

```
<body>
    <button onclick="sortReverse()">Click</button>
    <table class="gallery">
    <tbody><tr id="tableRow"><!-- id for test code, may remvoe later -->
        <td valign="top" id="19851"><a href="85-3.pdf#zoom=100" target="_blank">
            <span style="color:#99ccff;">1985</span> Jul<br><img src="pl_thumbs/1985-07_thumb.jpg">
        </a></td>
        <td valign="top" id="19861"><a href="86-0102.pdf#zoom=100" target="_blank">
            <span style="color:#99ccff;">1986</span> Jan-Feb<br><img src="pl_thumbs/1986-01-02_thumb.jpg">
        </a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>

    // Remember to include JQuery library.
    <script>
        function sortReverse(){
            // Select the parent element by id.
            var row = $("#tableRow");
            // Get all the children (columns)
            var columns = $.makeArray($("#tableRow > td"));
            // empty the parent content
            row.empty();
            // Append the reversed children array to the parent
            row.append(columns.reverse());
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: To MikeNQ: Thanks for the code example suggestion. I won't be able to get to it today. I'm assuming the id for getElementById("tableRow") will go in the TR tags. I can certainly enter an array (itemList)...but was wondering what would be required for it to detect the IDs and sort them, rather than referring back to an array? The IDs look like this: 19981, 19982, 20041, 20044, etc. and are each unique with the year and 1-4 to indicate which quarter issue it is. I don't want a grid for this, as it takes up a lot of page space. They can open the show/hide TOC at page bottom, and see more. -Thanks

Comment: If I understand it right, you would like to get the id from the html page elements? It can be done, but require a lot of html parsing with javascript which is not recommend. The most logical way is, for each document, create an Object that have all the detail of a document, then put all the Objects into an array and sort them based on one of the attribute.  
You can see it as a separation of UI layer and Application layer. In all terms: performance, scalability and maintenance, having the html visualize the data of Javascript is better.

Comment: Today I attempted to implement the script you provided. Although it replaced my page HTML with the ordered data in the array, it would not display and sort the formatted HTML TD tags' content. Script used as is, id="tableRow"  added to single TR tag, numbers matching the array list items were used as IDs in the TD tags, button added. Something I'm not doing right, I'm sure.

Comment: Could I take a look at your code, please paste the code in the original post.

Comment: Note: Code is added in original post: lines in main page with iframe, and lines from iframe's inner page file.

Comment: In the Html code you provided, I cannot see the <tr> tag with id="tableRow", thus the script cannot find such element. In the html code, you seem to be missing an <a> tag there. Also, as mentioned in my previous comment, it is better if you assign all the information to a Javascript object in each of its property, that will allow you to manipulate them better.

Comment: That's correct...just showing you the HTML it was tried in. I put the code in exactly as indicated and tested it. I took it out after telling you and waiting for your response, as these are live web site files. The code has been replaced temporarily on the site and is reposted above in pertinent part (shortened by many rows). No anchor tag missing that I can see in the example code. The script "is" working; however, it is sorting the IDs as though they were the data, rather than the columns they pertain to. - Thanks, Doug

Comment: That is exactly the point. Think of it this way, what the script doing is not sorting the column. It sorts the data array (Javascript array object) containing information and display each element of the array in a column. Html in the end is used as the interface for displaying data.

Comment: I suppose it is the point of what you're saying. However, my original inquiry was: "What I want to do: Create a toggle-link reverse column display order so that the newest columns appear to the left and oldest to the right when desired." So, my question is how can I apply this or another script to sort the column order in the row, in a similar way that many scripts out there sort the order of the rows in a column. Hope I'm being clear enough. Thanks for giving the idea a look.

Comment: Sorry that I missed your question, with that as the strict requirement, I have updated the answer.

Comment: After your update, I was able to implement the new script and it works perfectly! Thanks!  :-) (thetransformer.us home page)

Comment: No problem, sir. Please mark the answer so this problem is resolved.